# Optional regular expression operator in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

In $string, I'm trying to phase out the first "-1" so the output of the string will be "test test test-Long.xml".

```
 $string = 'test test test-1-Long.xml'

 $string -replace '^(.*)-?\d?(-?.*)\.xml$', '$1$2'
```

My issue is that I need to make that same first "-1" pattern optional, as both the hyphen and number could not be there as well.

Why is the "`?`" operator not working? I've also tried `{0,1}` after each as well with no luck.

Comment: Doesn't `$string -replace '^(.*)-\d+\b(.*)\.xml$', '$1$2'` work as expected? You do not need any optional groups. Note that when there is no match, `replace` will return the string unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Regexes are greedy, so the engine can't decide what to match, and it is ambiguous.

I am not sure it's the best solution, but I could make it work this way:

```
$string -replace '^([^\-]*)-?\d?(-?.*)\.xml$', '$1$2'
```

Sole change: the first group must not contain the dash: that kind of "balances" the regex, avoiding the greedyness and that yields:

```
test test test-Long
```

Note: the output is not `test test test-Long.xml` as required in your answer. To do that, simply remove the *xml* suffix:

```
$string -replace '^([^\-]*)-?\d?(-?.*)', '$1$2'
```

Comment: This works great with 'test test test-1-Long.xml', but with the input of 'test test test-Long.xml' it returns 'test test testLong.xml', the first hyphen and first digit and the 2nd hyphen all need to be optional.

Comment: This will do the wrong thing in the situation `test test test--Long.xml` or `test test test-1Long.xml`. The `-1` could be in a optional non-capturing group though: `(?:-\d)?`

Comment: @Laterade: You want `testLong.xml` or `test-Long.xml` in the end? I'm confused

Comment: @PaulHicks: your trick is better but given the user input, I get `test test test-Long.xml` with your code or my lame code. Still not clear what the OP wants...

Comment: The *regexes are greedy* statement is false. There is a greedy subpattern here, and it is the culprit. However, no explanation is given why.

Answer (score 0):

The `$string -replace '^(.*?)(?:-\d+)?(-.*?)\.xml$', '$1$2'` should work if the hyphen is obligatory in the input. Or `$string -replace '^((?:(?!-\d+).)*)(?:-\d+)?(.*)\.xml$', '$1$2'` in case the input may have no hyphen.

See the [regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/hN3pZ3/1) and [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/hN3pZ3/3).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ characters other than a newline as few as possible (as the `*?` quantifier is *lazy*) up to the first (**NOTE**: to increase regex performance, you may use a tempered greedy token based pattern instead of `(.*?)` - `((?:(?!-\d+).)*)` that matches any text, but `-`+`1 or more digits`, thus, acting similarly to negated character class, but for a sequence of symbols)
- `(?:-\d+)?` - non-capturing group with a greedy `?` quantifier (so, this group has more priority for the regex engine, the previous capture will end before this pattern) capturing a hyphen followed with one or more digits
- `(-.*?)` - Group 3 capturing an obligatory `-` and any 0+ chars other than LF, as few as possible up to
- `\.xml` - literal text `.xml`
- `$`  - end of string.

> Why is the "?" operator not working?

It is not true. The quantifier `?` works well as it matches one or *zero* occurrences of the quantified subpattern. However, the issue arises in combination with the first `.*` greedy dot matching subpattern. See [your regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/rZ4tL9/1): the first capture group grabs the whole substring up to the last `.xml`, and the second group is empty. Why?

Because of backtracking and how greedy quantifier works. The `.*` matches any characters, but a newline, as many as possible. Thus, it grabs the whole string up to the end. Then, backtracking starts: one character at a time is given back and tested against the subsequent subpatterns.

What are they? `-?\d?(-?.*)` - all of them can match an empty string. The `-?` matches an empty string before `.xml`, ok, `\d?` matches there as well, `-?` and `.*` also matches there.

However, the `.*` grabs the whole string again, but there is the `\.xml` pattern to accommodate. So, the second capture group is just empty. In fact, there are more steps the regex engine performs (see the [*regex debugger*](https://regex101.com/r/rZ4tL9/1) page), but the main idea is like that.